# Compute Marginal Probability Mass Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ have probability mass function $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = p^2(1-p)^{y-2}\textbf{1}_{\{ x<y \}}$ for positive integers $x$ and $y$, and $p \in (0,1)$.

Find the marginal pmfs of $Y$ and $X$.

So far, I found that for $y\in \{ 2,3,...\}$, $f_Y(y) = \sum_{x=1}^{y-1}p^2(1-p)^{y-2} = (y-1)p^2(1-p)^{y-2} = \binom{y-1}{2-1}p^2(1-p)^{y-2}$. Which is the pmf for a negative binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and $r=2$.

However I am stuck on computing the marginal pmf for $X$. All I have is, for $x\in \{ 1,2,3,...\}$, $f_X(x) = \sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty} p^2(1-p)^{y-2}$.

I am not sure what to do from this point. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I am stuck on computing the marginal pmf for X

You did start in the right way:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X=x) &=p^2\sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{y-2}\\[1ex]&=p^2(1-p)^{x-1}\sum_{(y-x-1)=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{y-x-1}\\[1ex]&=p^2(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^t}_{\text{geometric series}}\\[2ex]&=p^2(1-p)^{x-1}\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}\\[1ex]&=p(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{1,2,3,\dots\}}(x)\end{align}$$

which is a **Geometric** pmf with parameter $p$

---

Your Y pmf is right, NB counting # trials to get 2 successes but your expression has a typo (I amended the wrong expression in your post)

$$\mathbb{P}[Y=y]=\binom{y-1}{2-1}p^{2}(1-p)^{y-2}$$

$y=2,3,4,\dots$

---

**Minor Remark**: Given that you are dealing with discrete rv's, it is better to use the notation $\mathbb{P}[X=x]$ instead of $f_X(x)$ which is usually used for densities

Comment: Much thanks to you two. Turning the sum into a geometric series was very clever. Im not sure I would have thought of that.